# Tracking score and rounds played using Sinatra

Tags: ruby, class, variables, routes, sinatra

I have spent the last two weeks building a Sinatra app, and I have hit my first major roadblock.  I have spent the last 3 days trying to find a solution, but need to ask for help.

I am building a small game using Sinatra, and I am having trouble understanding a concept.

The game tracks rounds and scores.

Here is some of my code:

```
#Player Class
class Player
    attr_accessor :name, :guess, :round_score, :total_score
    def initialize 
        @guess = 0
        @round_score = 0
        @total_score = 0
    end
end

#Tracks Round
class RoundCount
    attr_accessor :round
    def initialize
        @round = 0
    end
    def count
        @round += 1
    end
end

helpers do
#New game function.  Makes set number of player classes in @@player array.
    def new_game(players) 
        @@i = RoundCount.new
        @@player = []
        players.times do |x|
            @@player[x] = Player.new
            @@player[x].name = "Player#{x}"
        end
    end

#Calculates score
        def player_score()
        params.each do |x, y|
            @@player.each do |z|
                if z.name == x 
                    z.guess = y.to_i
                    z.round_score = (y.to_i - @@movie[@@i.round].ratings['critics_score'].to_i).abs
                    z.total_score += (y.to_i - @@movie[@@i.round].ratings['critics_score'].to_i).abs
                end
            end
        end
    end

get '/' do
    slim :home
end

get '/players' do
    slim :players
end

post '/numplayers' do
    new_game(params[:numplayers].to_i)
    slim :names
end

post '/names' do
    slim :titles
end
```

Currently the program gives me the error "warning: class variable access from topelevel" and is affected by other users who play at the same time on seperate computers.

I need help understanding how to track players scores and the round of the game in each view, in a way that isn't affected by other players running a different game.

Any suggestions on how to avoid using class variables for round and score, while retaining a way to access them in each route and view?

Comment: I used session variables.  First I tried using ' enable :sessions ' however that resulted in a long cookie error.  The code which worked was ' use Rack::Session::Pool '.  Then as an example of how I used session variables: ' @@player[x].name = "Player#{x}" ' was replaced with ' session[:player][x].name = "Player#{x}" '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Sessions or Cookies

Generally, keeping server-side state through class variables will make your life harder. There's also usually more than one way to do anything, but for your use case I'd recommend that you store your state in a [session variable](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions) or a [cookie](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/cookies.html).

You could then store your state in any serializable object, such as a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html), [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html), [Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Struct.html), or [OpenSruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html). This will allow for concurrent users, and do away with the need for the class variables you're currently using.

Comment: I had looked at using a session variable before, however I didn't pursue it too closely as I didn't want the game to rely on cookies.  I now realize that session variables are seperate from cookies.  They sound perfect for my application.  While cookies persist until the cookie is removed, session variables only persist while the browser is open.  Thank you!